# Google's Web Service API via iOS requires a server?

Tags: ios, web-services, google-places-api

I've seen in a few tutorials that Google's Places Web Service API is prohibited from being used directly from a mobile device. Is this still true?

I wouldn't call it easy, but after setting up a server key without any restricted IPs/Referrers, it seems to function just fine for me. I have searched quite a bit for official documentation from Google that specifies this to be the case, but I have yet to find anything concrete. I could see it being a good idea for additional security, but is it a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The Places API Policies document has a section Mobile Applications, but doesn't mention any restriction regarding using web service directly from a mobile device.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies